# dup2 a socket to a file

Tags: c, linux, sockets, dup

All, winter comes, plz keep warm and keep healthy.
During the meditation about the work, I got some question about the function of fd dup2
.
I create a socket server, and a client. the server send, the client receive data.
But Now I want to dup2 the server socket fd to a file df in order to let the client read data directly from a file located in server.
I write like

```
while(socketdf = accept(...))
{
 dup2(filefd , socketfd);
}
```

However, it doesnot work
is this possible?
Can you give me any advice on this?
Thanx

Comment: Hi, all what if it is a shared memory fd, not a file fd?

Answer (score 4):

`dup2()` doesn't work like that -- what you're ending up doing here is closing `socketfd` and replacing it with a copy of `filefd`.

There is no way to directly plug a socket into a file like what you're trying to do here -- you will need to "pump" data from the file to the socket in your application. The `sendfile()` system call will simplify things considerably, though.

Comment: Sorry, `sendfile(2)` only works when the `in_fd` parameter supports `mmap(2)`-like operations -- no sockets allowed.

Comment: Hrm, I interpreted the question the other way around -- I thought he wanted to let the server store data to a file that he could feed to clients at a later date. (By the way, cool dog graviwhatsit.)

Comment: The critical wording I saw was "let the client read data directly from a file located in server". That part seems pretty unambiguous.

Comment: Hahaha, amazing, we both thought we had unambiguous interpretations that are polar opposites. I sure hope you're right, it'll be way easier for him if you are. :)

Comment: Beware that `sendfile(2)` is `Not specified in POSIX.1-2001, or other standards.

Other UNIX systems implement sendfile() with different semantics and prototypes. It should not be used in portable programs.` according to the man page.

Comment: @duskwuff: hi, what if it is a shared memory fd? not a file fd

Comment: @Macroideal: whatever fd it would be, dup2() effectively does close(oldfd); copy(newfd, oldfd); and you will have your socket closed. No luck and no easy way here.